# MVC Model property not updated when accessed in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this in my cshtml file:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Vehicles.Count; i++){
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Vehicles[i].Selected)}
```

Basically Model.Vehicles is a List of vehicles and the Selected property is a bool...

I have a button that when clicked, calls this function:

```
function delSel(){
    var vehicles = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Vehicles))';
    var selIDs = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i ++)
    {
        if (vehicles[i].Selected == "true") {
            selIDs = selIDs + vehicles[i].ID + ",";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('CRVehicleIDs').value = selIDs;
}
```

My problem is, eventhough the Checkbox is checked, the value of the Selected property is always equal to false... Is there a better way to get the selected items in this case?

Comment: `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Vehicles))` is the original model. not the values which may have been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var vehicles = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Vehicles))';
```

This will not work as you are expecting, the razor syntax is rendered server side which means the value of this will not get updated when a user clicks on the checkboxes.

What you can do however is when you create you're checkboxes, give them an ID using `i` variable in your for loop.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Vehicles[i].Selected, new { id = "checkbx_" + i })
```

Then you can iterate through your checkboxes with a for loop.

```
function delSel(){
    var vehicles = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Vehicles));
    var selIDs = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i ++)
    {
        if (document.getElementById('checkbx_' + i).checked) {
            selIDs = selIDs + vehicles[i].ID + ",";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('CRVehicleIDs').value = selIDs;
}
```

Comment: I see... I'll do what you suggest and then I'll get back after... :) Thank you... :)

Comment: Yay! It worked! Thank you so much... But a change in your answer... instead of checking for the value, I've check the checked property...

Instead of this:
if (document.getElementById('checkbx_' + i).value)

I checked this:
if (document.getElementById('checkbx_' + i).checked)

Answer (score 0):

You're rendering `this.Model.Vehicles` to JSON which is then rendered within Javascript single-quotes - this will likely result in invalid Javascript syntax when accessed in a browser because JSON object property names are also enclosed in quotes.

Remove the quotes around `@Html.Raw`.

You would have spotted this if you looked at the rendered HTML of the page and saw that a large chunk of it would be covered in syntax errors.

Other tips:

- JavaScript is typically styled with the opening brace on the same line as the keyword (as with Java), not the line below (as C#). It's also customary to use `camelCase` for JavaScript objects, not `TitleCase`. You should be able to customize your JSON-generator to use `camelCase`, refer to the documentation.
- Boolean properties tend to be prefixed with `Is`, so it would be `IsSelected` (or `isSelected` in camelCase).
- This is suboptimal:

  ```
  if( vehicles[i].Selected == "true" ) {
  ```

  Assuming that the `Selected` property is rendered as Javascript boolean value, you need only act on it directly:

  ```
  if( vehicles[i].Selected ) {
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply... I enclosed the @Html.Raw with single quotes because it was suggested... Without them there's always a warning saying syntax error but the code still words... Having you said that, I'll just remove them... :)

Comment: @IanCaparanga If you're getting syntax errors without the quotes then something else is wrong. Please post the **rendered** output to your question so we can take a look.

Comment: @IanCaparanga, You can ignore the syntax error - which will underline the semi-colon at the end (its just an annoying issue with the Razor engine but the code will still run fine)

Comment: I've been ignoring it for quite sometime... I literally just added it before this post... Again, thank you so much for this tip...